# Is it possible to destructure data class' instance into class' properties?

Tags: kotlin

I have a data class `MyDataClass`:

```
data class MyDataClass(val a: Int, val b: Int)
```

and a class `MyClass` with two properties. I want to destructure an instance of `MyDataClass`, so `a` and `b` are assigned to `MyClass` properties, instead of declare new variables:

```
class MyClass {

  val a: Int
  val b: Int

  init {
    val mdc = MyDataClass(1, 4)
    (a, b) = mdc //error
  }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, destructuring declarations are only allowed for local variables and lambda parameters.

Also, they are only used to *create* multiple local variables at once. So `val (a, b) = mdc` is allowed, but
`(a, b) = mdc` is invalid syntax, even if `a` and `b` are not properties.

Answer (score 1):

Although destructuring declaration are only allowed for local you can still do something like this

```
class MyClass {

    val a: Int
    val b: Int

    init {
        val (a, b) = MyDataClass(1, 4)
        this.a = a
        this.b = b
    }
}
```