# How can I use destructuring declarations in a class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

At present, I use Code A in my project, I think it's too complex.

But Code B get the following error

*Destructuring declarations are only allowed for local variables/values*

How can I optimize Code A ?

**Code A**

```
class PreferenceParameterState private constructor(context: Context) {
    var openEditDialog by mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

    fun set_OpenEditDialog(isShow: Boolean) {
        openEditDialog = isShow
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
class PreferenceParameterState private constructor(context: Context) {
    val (openEditDialog, set_OpenEditDialog) = mutableStateOf(false)  
}
```

**Added Content**

To Tenfour04: Thanks!

The Code C comes from the official [project](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetchat/app/src/main/java/com/example/compose/jetchat/MainViewModel.kt).

In Code C,  the public `function  fun openDrawer()`  and  `fun resetOpenDrawerAction()`  can change `val drawerShouldBeOpened` finally.

By your opinion,  Code D would be good way, but in fact , I seldom see Code D, and Code C is often.

If I  optimize Code A,  shoud I use Code E ?

**Code C**

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _drawerShouldBeOpened = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val drawerShouldBeOpened = _drawerShouldBeOpened.asStateFlow()

    fun openDrawer() {
        _drawerShouldBeOpened.value = true
    }

    fun resetOpenDrawerAction() {
        _drawerShouldBeOpened.value = false
    }
}
```

**Code D**

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var drawerShouldBeOpened = MutableStateFlow(false)
}
```

**Code E**

```
class PreferenceParameterState private constructor(context: Context) {
    var openEditDialog by mutableStateOf(false) 
}
```

**Added Content Again:**

To Tenfour04: Thanks!

The Code F  comes from another [project](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetsurvey/app/src/main/java/com/example/compose/jetsurvey/survey/SurveyViewModel.kt)

And Code F is not working with a `Flow`,  by your opinion, Code F should be optimized as Code G, is it correct?

**Code F**

```
    private val _freeTimeResponse = mutableStateListOf<Int>()
    val freeTimeResponse: List<Int>
        get() = _freeTimeResponse

    private val _superheroResponse = mutableStateOf<Superhero?>(null)
    val superheroResponse: Superhero?
        get() = _superheroResponse.value

    private val _takeawayResponse = mutableStateOf<Long?>(null)
    val takeawayResponse: Long?
        get() = _takeawayResponse.value

    private val _feelingAboutSelfiesResponse = mutableStateOf<Float?>(null)
    val feelingAboutSelfiesResponse: Float?
        get() = _feelingAboutSelfiesResponse.value

    private val _selfieUri = mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null)
    val selfieUri
        get() = _selfieUri.value


  fun onSuperheroResponse(superhero: Superhero) {
        _superheroResponse.value = superhero
        _isNextEnabled.value = getIsNextEnabled()
    }
```

**Code G**

```
var freeTimeResponse by mutableStateListOf<Int>()

var superheroResponse by mutableStateOf<Superhero?>(null)     

var takeawayResponse by mutableStateOf<Long?>(null)

...
```

Comment: The approach used in the second instance is not supported. Destructuring is used to break an object into a set of properties & cannot be used to create a getter and setter for a property. You could simply use `var openEditDialog by mutableStateOf(false)`.

Comment: The optimum version of Code A is to remove `private set` and the setter function. Why add that convolution for setting the value of your property?

Comment: Thanks! I hope that the `openEditDialog` can be access outside the class `PreferenceParameterState`, and it can be only changed inside the class, so I add `private set`

Comment: `val (openEditDialog, set_OpenEditDialog) = mutableStateOf(false) ` is good way,  unfortunately. `Destructuring declarations are only allowed for local variables/values`

Comment: But you can still change it from outside the class because you have passed along the setting to the public function `set_OpenEditDialog`. What is the purpose of `set_OpenEditDialog`? Can you just remove it and your problem is solved?

Comment: You might want it to work that way, but it doesn't and won't.  You have to do it in the style of Option A.

Comment: Thanks!  @Tenfour04 ,  would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: Code C and Code D are very different from the rest of them. They are working with a Flow, not State. You don’t want to turn a flow directly into a property because Flows are collected rather than just reading the current value. Code D is absolutely terrible. You wouldn’t want to change from one flow to another in the property because it will orphan all the collectors of the previous flow—they wouldn’t know there’s a new flow to collect and it defeats the purpose of using a flow. Code E is preferable to Code A.

Comment: Thanks! @Tenfour04 , would you please to see my added content again in the question?

Comment: No, that situation in Code F is different. In some of their functions, they are changing multiple states, so that is not the same as simply using a property's setter. Also, they are not using the State as a property delegate (they can't because of how they are changing multiple states at once). The difference with Code A is that in Code A you have hidden the property setter only to expose the *exact same functionality* through the separate function. Even semantically, "on superhero response" does not mean the same thing as "set superhero response"--its doing more than just setting the value.

Comment: Is there any additional functionality in the getter and setter? If not, there is no difference between making it public or creating a custom getter/setter.

Comment: Something similar, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46622791/9636037

Comment: Hi @HelloCW, Added an answer, kindly comment if it is not clear. It's already quite long, so I didn't add more. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by sharing how destructuring works.

You can destructure data when the class has `fun componentN()` for the number of components you want to destructure it to.

**Data class destructuring**

A `data class` has this support out of the box by Kotlin similar to `toString()`, `equals()`, and `hashCode()`.

Example,

```
data class DataClassDestructuring(
    val a: Int,
    val b: Int,
)
```

Can be destructured like this,

```
fun test() {
    val (dataClassA, dataClassB) = DataClassDestructuring(1, 2)
}
```

**Custom class destructuring**

We can also have destructuring for other classes using `operator fun componentN()`  methods.

```
class CustomDestructureClass(
    private val x: Int = 0,
    private val y: Int = 0,
) {
    operator fun component1(): Int {
        return x
    }

    operator fun component2(): Int {
        return y
    }
}
```

This can be destructured like this,

```
fun test() {
    val (customClassX, customClassY) = CustomDestructureClass(1, 2)
}
```

**MutableState destructuring**

As `MutableState` is defined like this, it also supports destructuring.

```
interface MutableState<T> : State<T> {
    override var value: T
    operator fun component1(): T
    operator fun component2(): (T) -> Unit
}

fun test() {
    val (state, setState) = mutableStateOf("")
}
```

**MutableStateFlow destructuring**

But, `MutableStateFlow` can not be destructured. If you look into its code you will not find the required component operator methods.

---

---

Now that we went through what destructuring is and how it works. Let's see what happens when we do it.

From the [Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html),

> This syntax is called a destructuring declaration. A destructuring declaration creates multiple variables at once.

This states that destructuring creates multiple variables at once.
So, why does it work when destructuring in a function like, but the same gives an error in a class?

```
fun test() {
    val (dataClassA, dataClassB) = DataClassDestructuring(1, 2) // Works
}

class DestructuringDemo {
    val (dataClassA, dataClassB) = DataClassDestructuring(1, 2) // Error
}
```

We can understand this from the error message,

> Destructuring declarations are only allowed for local variables/values.

Looking into [Kotlin Docs for Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html), we can observe that the class defines properties and not variables (or [fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-fields) in this context) directly.

As properties support getter and setter, this does not work for destructuring.

---

---

The last aspect of the question was how to use `MutableState` in a class like ViewModel.

There is no correct answer for this, it depends on what you want.

Code A - Public getter and private setter

```
var openEditDialog by mutableStateOf(false)
    private set
```

Code E - Public getter and public setter

```
var openEditDialog by mutableStateOf(false)
```

Modified Code E changing `val` to `var` - Public getter and immutable (so no setter)

```
val openEditDialog by mutableStateOf(false)
```

Code F - Using [Kotlin Backing property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#backing-properties)

```
private val _superheroResponse = mutableStateOf<Superhero?>(null)
val superheroResponse: Superhero?
    get() = _superheroResponse.value
```

Other options - You can have getters and setter declared along with the property like [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters)

---

---

How to choose?

Before adding further info, I would like to add this as well Google Devs have mentioned that is fine to add mutable state in ViewModel, but there is mixed opinion on whether it is a good approach as it is from Compose Runtime package.

I personally prefer using Flow in ViewModel over Compose State. This is completely a personal opinion.

If you are proceeding with having Compose state in ViewModel, this would be a good approach.

```
private val _superheroResponse = mutableStateOf<Int?>(null)
val superheroResponse: State<Int?>
    get() = _superheroResponse
```

The public `superheroResponse` should have the type mentioned explicitly as `State` and not `MutableState`. Then you can have a custom getter and setter to perform any validation or business operations before or after retrieving or updating the value.

The code E in the question is returning the value using `.value`, but we are returning the state here and hence this can be observed in the Composable.

Comment: Thanks! Is `Code E - Public getter and public setter` the better than `Code A - Public getter and private setter` ?

Comment: Added more details at the last.

Comment: Thanks!  your latest code `private val _superheroResponse = mutableStateOf<Int?>(null)
val superheroResponse: State<Int?>
    get() = _superheroResponse` just like Code A  ( Public getter and private setter ) `var openEditDialog by mutableStateOf(false)
    private set`  based usage.

Comment: Not exactly, the type of data returned has an impact as well. Making the `State` getter public and the `MutableState` getter public is not the same. For reference - https://pl.kotl.in/rO5aci0x2

Comment: Dave Leeds explains a lot more on this in this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7hLJsLGhJA&t=337s