# How does Android Studio Compiler generate method name for var editText by mutableStateOf("") automatically?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When I compile Code A, I get an error, the system prompt me exists a method name `setEditText`.

But  `fun setIsShowEditDialog(isShow:Boolean)` is OK without prompt exists a method name  `setIsShowEditDialog`, why?

I have to change `fun setEditText(input:String)` to `fun set_EditText(input:String)`, it's OK to compile.

But  Android Studio prompt me a warning information: *Function name 'set_EditText' should not contain underscores* , why ?

**Code A**

```
class EditDialogState private constructor(context: Context) {

    var isShowEditDialog by mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

    var editText by  mutableStateOf("")
        private  set

    fun setIsShowEditDialog(isShow:Boolean) {    //It's OK
        isShowEditDialog = isShow
    }

    fun setEditText(input:String) {             //Compile Error
        editText = input
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no point in what you're doing. Remove the `setEditText` method and the `private set` of the property, and you'll have effectively the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! The reason  I use `private set` is  to be access outside the class, and to be only changed inside the class, would you please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76528454/how-can-i-use-destructuring-declarations-in-a-class-in-kotlin

Comment: But I don't know if it's a good way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the implementation details of Kotlin property setter and getter method names.

```
class MyTemp {
    var showEditDialog by mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

    var isNewShowEditDialog by mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

    // Will give error
    fun getShowEditDialog(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    // Will give error
    fun setShowEditDialog(isShow: Boolean) {}

    // Will give error
    fun isNewShowEditDialog(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    // Will give error
    fun setNewShowEditDialog(isShow: Boolean) {}
}
```

We can see special handling for variables with the prefix "is".
This causes the difference you are observing.
This is applicable to other types as well like strings.

Comment: Thanks! Is it not a good way to set `var showEditDialog by mutableStateOf(false)` as ` private set` ?  would you please the related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76528454/how-can-i-use-destructuring-declarations-in-a-class-in-kotlin